# hibernate inheritance / Spring java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf, inheritance

I'm working on project with hibernate and spring. I'm working with Hibernate inheritance (Table per concrete class ).
When i submit a form from my JSF page i get java.lang.NullPointerException.

here is my code:

my controller class:

```
public class MarchandAssociationController implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

//attribute


@Autowired
MarchandPAssociationBo mAssocBo;

MarchandPAssociation mAssociation=new MarchandPAssociation();


public String addMarchandAssociation(){

    System.out.println("addAssociation");

    //seting values in mAssociation;
    mAssocBo.addAssociation(mAssociation);

    return "Signup_association.xhtml";
}




public MarchandPAssociationBo getmAssocBo() {
    return mAssocBo;
}


public void setmAssocBo(MarchandPAssociationBo mAssocBo) {
    this.mAssocBo = mAssocBo;
}

DAO class:
public class MarchandPAssociationDaoImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport implements MarchandPAssociationDao{
@Override
public void addAssociation(MarchandPAssociation marchand) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println("DAO: ");
    getHibernateTemplate().setCheckWriteOperations(false);
    getHibernateTemplate().save(marchand);
}
```

}

BO Class (service class)

```
public class MarchandPAssociationBoImpl implements MarchandPAssociationBo {


MarchandPAssociationDao mPAssociationDao;

@Override
public void addAssociation(MarchandPAssociation marchandPAssociation) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println("Bo: Add assoc");
    mPAssociationDao.addAssociation(marchandPAssociation);

}
public MarchandPAssociationDao getmPAssociationDao() {
    return mPAssociationDao;
}
public void setmPAssociationDao(MarchandPAssociationDao mPAssociationDao) {
    this.mPAssociationDao = mPAssociationDao;
}
```

}

hibernate mapping file :

```
    <discriminator column="discriminator" type="string" not-null="true" length="20"/>

    <property name="nom" type="string">
        <column name="nom" length="40" not-null="false"/><!-- not-null="true" to add from this -->
    </property>
    <property name="prenom" type="string">
        <column name="prenom" length="40"  not-null="false"/>
    </property>
    <property name="email" type="string">
        <column name="email" length="80"  not-null="false"/>
    </property>
    <property name="password" type="string">
        <column name="password" length="60" not-null="false" />
    </property>
    <property name="sexe" type="string">
        <column name="sexe" length="10"  not-null="false"/>
    </property>
    <property name="situationProfetionnelle" type="string">
        <column name="situation_profetionnelle" length="60"  not-null="false"/>
    </property>
    <property name="dateNaissance" type="date">
        <column name="date_naissance" length="10" not-null="false"/>
    </property>
    <property name="paysMarchand" type="string">
        <column name="pays_marchand" length="60"  />
    </property>
    <property name="adresseMarchand" type="string">
        <column name="adresse_marchand" length="80"  not-null="false"/>
    </property>
    <property name="villeMarchand" type="string">
        <column name="ville_marchand" length="60"  not-null="false"/>
    </property>
    <property name="nationalite" type="string">
        <column name="nationalite" length="60"  not-null="false"/>
    </property>
    <property name="telMarchand" type="string">
        <column name="tel_marchand" length="20"  not-null="false"/>
    </property>
    <property name="site_app" type="boolean">
        <column name="site/app"  /> <!-- not-null="true" to this -->
    </property>

    <subclass name="com.Dialpass.model.MarchandPAssociation" discriminator-value="Association">
            <property name="nomStructure" type="string">
                <column name="nom_structure" length="60" />
            </property>
            <property name="adresseStructure" type="string">
                <column name="adresse_structure" length="80" />
            </property>
            <property name="paysStructure" type="string">
                <column name="pays_structure" length="60" />
            </property>
            <property name="villeStructure" type="string">
                <column name="ville_structure" length="60" />
            </property>
            <property name="numeroEnregistrement" type="string">
                <column name="numero_enregistrement" length="30" />
            </property>
            <property name="site" type="string">
                <column name="site" length="100" />
            </property>
            <property name="app" type="string">
                <column name="app" length="100" />
            </property>

    </subclass>


</class>
```

hibernat esession factory file (.xml)

```
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>com/Dialpass/hibernate/MarchandP.hbm.xml</value>

        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Can you help ? thanks

Stack Trace :

j

```
avax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.Dialpass.controller.MarchandAssociationController.addMarchandAssociation(MarchandAssociationController.java:85)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:277)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:273)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    ... 27 more
```

Comment: @Dirk here is the Stackrace

Comment: And what line in MerchantAssociationController is the 85?

Comment: Are you sure the mAssocBO in you controller gets wired?

Comment: the line 85 in MerchantAssociationController is a getter of a attribute  public String getPrenom() {
  return prenom;
 }

Comment: I think that the problem come from  the mAssocBo ... but i don't know where is exactly the problem

Comment: According to your stacktrace the NPE is thrown in line 85. Could you check that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that in your MarchandAssociationController Class you should add a getter/setter for your mAssociation.